# Can a database running in a server refuse a connection, and once fixed, the server itself refuses it?

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, ufw

I'm connecting to a Postgresql database running in an Ubuntu server. I had no problem doing this from the office but when I tried connecting from home, the connection was refused.

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XX.XXX.XX.XX", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

So, I added my ip to the conf file

```
host    all             postgres        XX.XXX.XX.XX            md5
```

Thinking I was done, a new error appeared:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "YYY.YY.YY.YY" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I added my ip to the server firewall and still the connection is refused and the same error keeps showing up, even if the server is running and accepting connections on port 5432
From ufw:

```
5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    XX.XXX.XX.XX
```

So, is it weird that at first the connection was refused by the database in the server, and then it was refused by the server itself and not the other way around?
Also, if the server is running and accepting connections in that port, what else can I try to fix my problem?

Comment: what's your Operating System? how did you install?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo I have Ubuntu 18.04, I installed Postgres by running `apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib`

Comment: What is the exact `pg_hba.conf` line? Did you reload PostgreSQL? What is the error message in the PostgreSQL log file (usually somewhere in `/var/log` in Ubuntu Linux)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Nothing really, last log is from a few days ago, not from now

Comment: Oh, right, you don't even reach the PostgreSQL server. Either it is a network problem, or your forgot to set `listen_addresses` to something different from `localhost`.

Comment: can you post whole pg_hba.conf replacing sensitive data? I guess something not posted here might be wrong or missing

Comment: While waiting for whole file posted check what is not well configured by comparing with this article: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html

Comment: As I was copying the file, I noticed my office IP had IP/32, and said 'all' instead of postgres. Changing this fixed the error.
 `host    all             all             officeIP/32   md5
`
So, `host    all             all             HomeIP/32   md5` instead of `host    all             postgres             officeIP   md5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the prbolem. In the conf file, instead of the line

```
host    all             postgres        XX.XXX.XX.XX            md5
```

I added

```
host    all             all        XX.XXX.XX.XX/32            md5
```

And now it works fine.